# Sikuli is throwing exception org.sikuli.api.robot.desktop.DesktopScreen.getSize

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, sikuli

When I run my code, I am getting below error. I am running my code on remote server using Selenium grid. Though when I run on my local machine code is working fine.

error is -----------

```html
`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
     at org.sikuli.api.robot.desktop.DesktopScreen.getSize(DesktopScreen.java:43)
     at org.sikuli.api.AbstractScreenRegion.<init>(AbstractScreenRegion.java:19)
     at org.sikuli.api.DefaultScreenRegion.<init>(DefaultScreenRegion.java:37)
     at org.sikuli.api.DesktopScreenRegion.<init>(DesktopScreenRegion.java:11)
 at          com.test.accenture.acp.onboardoperation.OnboardingOperationScenario.I_click_on_Choose_file(OnboardingOperationScenario.java:3596)
 at ✽.Then I click on Choose file(com/test/accenture/acp/onboardoperation/0002CreateBlueprint.feature:19)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
 at sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getScreenDevices(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:72)
 at org.sikuli.api.robot.desktop.AWTDesktop.<clinit>(AWTDesktop.java:27)
 at org.sikuli.api.robot.desktop.DesktopScreen.getSize(DesktopScreen.java:43)
 at org.sikuli.api.AbstractScreenRegion.<init>(AbstractScreenRegion.java:19)
 at org.sikuli.api.DefaultScreenRegion.<init>(DefaultScreenRegion.java:37)
 at org.sikuli.api.DesktopScreenRegion.<init>(DesktopScreenRegion.java:11)
 at com.test.accenture.acp.onboardoperation.OnboardingOperationScenario.I_click_on_Choose_file(OnboardingOperationScenario.java:3596)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:37)
 at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:44)
 at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:223)
 at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
 at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
 at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:36)
 at cucumber.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:76)
 at cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:65)
 at cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:20)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
 at cucumber.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:72)
 at cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:75)
 at cucumber.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:36)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
 at cucumber.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:80)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:158)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:86)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
 at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)
    `
```

System

Windows server R2 datacenter / 64 bit operating system
sikuli 1.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Does your remote server have a UI?  Or is there an active desktop session when you are running this?  Sikuli requires an active desktop session (on a remote server, this usually requires someone to be logged in via RDP or VNC).

Comment: aholt is correct. The exception correctly says - Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.